# ConcurrentModificationException when using indexOf() in an ArrayList

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, concurrency

I'm getting ConcurrentModificationException when I'am just iterating through an ArrayList and using indexOf() in the loop for my application logic. Can someone explain the reason behind this? From what I read, this should happen if I try to add/remove an item to/from the list while I'm still iterating. Am I missing some thing here?

```
for (SomeClass c : listOfSomeClass)) {
            listOfSomeClass.indexOf(c);
        }
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with the `indexOf`. `listOfSomeClass` is being modified elsewhere.

Comment: @AndyTurner you mean some other thread?

Comment: If that is all that is in your loop body, yes, it would have to be another thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having a concurrency issues, then, instead of you do:

```
ArrayList<SomeClass> listOfSomeClass = new ArrayList<>();
```

Try to do:

```
CopyOnWriteArrayList<SomeClass> contas = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
```

'CopyOnWriteArrayList' is a thread-safe variant of java.util.ArrayList in which all mutative operations (add, set, and so on) are implemented by making a fresh copy of the underlying array.

This is ordinarily too costly, but may be more efficient than alternatives when traversal operations vastly outnumber mutations, and is useful when you cannot or don't want to synchronize traversals, yet need to preclude interference among concurrent threads.

font: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html

There are another options to solve your problem, but we need to see all your code to suggest a better help.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to delete or add new item when you traverse list,you should use the ListIterator.This the code

```
package com.test.dal;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class LTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> listOfSomeClass = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfSomeClass.add("1");
        listOfSomeClass.add("2");
        listOfSomeClass.add("3");
        listOfSomeClass.add("4");
        ListIterator<String> iterator = listOfSomeClass.listIterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String item = iterator.next();
            if (item.equals("2"))
                iterator.remove();
            else if (item.equals("4"))
                iterator.add("5");
        }
        System.out.println(listOfSomeClass);
    }
}
```